# Spring data JPA with subquery in where clause

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have below query and wanted to see if Spring data JPA supports below and how can I achieve it

```
select * from table_one a where a.uid IN :userids and a.cdate =
(select max(cdate) from table_one)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Query` annotation to specify such a query in an interface extended from `@JpaRepository`. Sample interface below:

```java
package io.github.devatherock.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import io.github.devatherock.domain.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = 
            "select * from table_one a where a.uid IN :userIds and a.cdate = (select max(cdate) from table_one)")
    List<User> findByIdAndCreatedDate(List<String> userIds);
}
```

You can find an application with sample usage(in tests) on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-demo/tree/spring-jpa)